# Hibernate with MS SQL Server 2012 issue with table locks and parallel query

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, hibernate, table-locking

I have a java thread that does the update of few tables in a transaction and there is another thread that reads the tables with read only transaction . The thread that reads the tables is waiting and not retuning the result and returns only after the other thread had done the update .

The case is different if DB is mysql where the update and query does happen parallel and no waiting . Am I missing something on MS SQL side . What needs to be done to make it parallel . Is this happening because of table locks in MS Sql Server .

*The MS Sql server hibernate setting :*

db.driverClassName = **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource**

db.dialect = **org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect**

Hibernate version : **v4.3.6.Final**

Connection pool : **HikariCP-java6 - v2.2.5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **T-SQL** you can use `UNLOCK` command, in [***this link***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e7z8d5hf(v=vs.80).aspx) you can see a full  description of it. also you can use `WITH (NOLOCK)` while selecting from table like:

```
SELECT *
FROM sample_table WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE --conditions
```

But in **Hibernate** with **MS SQL Server** I really don't know how to implement `NOLOCK` if you find a solution for it tell us I'll follow this question.

Comment: Thanks for the  reply . I still haven't figured out the solution . I probably will use your solution by knocking of hibernate and using jdbc templates to do the update

Comment: you are welcome, I hope you'll fix the issue soon. good luck.